# how to make gradle codestyle check to use intellij's code style file

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I have a customized code style that is stored inside `.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml` file. so I wonder if it is possible to run the check when Gradle's build command is issued.

I've found how to run google java code style via Gradle command but I cannot make it to use Intellij's XML file. What I want is a single file to store everything about code style, that can be used by both Intellij and Gradle.